# Group number of divs using li

Tags: php, html-lists, grouping

I have 8 or more products in the database:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->products)){ 
  echo "<ul>"; 
        foreach ($this->products as $product){ 
?>
    8 items inserted here
<?
        }
  echo "</ul>"; 
      }
php?>
```

So what I want is the 8 or more products on the database will be placed like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <div>Product here</div>
     <div>Product here</div>
     <div>Product here</div>
     <div>Product here</div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div>Product here</div>
     <div>Product here</div>
     <div>Product here</div>
     <div>Product here</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

so 4 products in every `<li>`. How do I do this and to know that this is from a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php if (!empty($this->products)){ 
      echo "<ul>"; 
            $counter = 1;
            foreach ($this->products as $product){
                if($counter == 1) echo '<li>';
                echo $product;
                if($counter==4) {$counter=0; echo '</li>';}
                $counter++;

            }
      echo "</ul>"; 
          }
  ?>
```

Comment: Since `$counter` is initially `0`, this will print the product before the first `li` tag.

Comment: @Th3Cuber You're right. My bad... I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the modulus operator in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to keep track of printing/inserting a closing/opening `li` tag every four products:

```
<?php 
  if (!empty($this->products)){ 
    echo "<ul>"; 
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($this->products as $product){ 
      if ($i % 4 == 1) echo "<li>";

      echo "<div>".$product."</div>";

      if ($i % 4 == 0) echo "</li>";

      $i++;
    }
    echo "</ul>"; 
  }
?>
```

For example, if `i` is initially `1`, we place an opening `li` tag and the product inside a `div`. We then increment `i`. When `i` reaches the value `4` (or any other multiple of 4) we want to close the `li` tag. After that, `i` will become `5`, and `5 % 4 = 1`, and so once again we will open another `li` tag.

Comment: thank you so much. let me try this one. BRB. :D

Comment: No problem! If I've solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the tick :)